# Google Maps - Disable Default Feature Layers via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an app that uses Google Maps (JavaScript). When I load the map, it includes a variety of places already included. For example, if I have the map focused on Chicago, IL, the United Center appears. I can click it and a tool tip appears.

I am putting push pins on the map with my own search results. If a user clicks a pushpin, I show them a tooltip. How do I only show tooltips for the pushpins that I add? Essentially, I want to disable the default tooltip approach and only use tooltips with my results.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable these by setting the `visibility` to `off` for that particular feature. You just need to set it in the `styles` property when you configure your map. Something like:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8337329,-87.7321555),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [ 
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

You can see a working code sample [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtpHarry/7yt8xtyh/).

There is a further reference which lists all the different types of features you can control on the Google Maps API under the [google.maps.MapTypeStyleFeatureType object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType).